# Need help with hiding an image within a post in a category

Tags: posts, categories, conditional-tags

On a standard category page I want to hide an image for a specific post, I've tried to using

```
<?php if(is_single('post_ID')) {
    echo "Hide Image";
    }
    else {
    echo "Show Image";
    }
?>
```

that I got from the WordPress conditional tags page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( get_the_ID() !== 45 ) {
    // Will run for all posts other than ID 45
}

if ( get_the_title() !== 'My Post' ) {
    // Will run for all posts that don't have the title "My Post"
}

if ( get_post_field( 'post_name' ) !== 'my-post' ) {
    // Will run for all posts that don't have the slug "my-post"
}
```